# how do i create multiple windows dns entries?

Tags: dns-server, domain-name-system

I have windows 2008 R2 and i have created 20 `.com` primary and secondary zones for the domains. Within each of these are `MX`, `A`, `SOA` and `NS` records.

I have done this manually and its taking me ages using the GUI Wizard.

I have the exact same to do with `.eu` domains.

Where are the .DNS files located? What is the fastest way to create these zones?

Comment: I feel your pain.

Comment: Its a nightmare and RSI is getting worse!

Answer (score 2):

You can script zone and resource record creation/modification with [dnscmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772069(v=ws.10).aspx).

If you want to just get down with a text editor, you can edit the zone files in `%systemroot%\System32\DNS`.

Comment: well the zones i have created are not even located in `System32\DNS` - My intention was to copy the files and then edit them

Comment: Did you create Active Directory Integrated zones? Do you have "Hide Operating System Files" turned off in Windows Explorer, etc?

Comment: primary and secondary zones for web domains. i have set the folder to display all hidden files. "Hide Operating System Files" ?? is that even an option?

Comment: Yes. It is an option. It's literally two radio buttons down from where you show hidden files.

Comment: i can see other .dns files... but not the new ones that were created. i have `Hide OS sys files` uncheckedt too.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell can be used to manage DNS, via WMI (in which case you could also use VBScript if that is your bag).

[Microsoft Scripting Guy blog has a detailed entry on this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/13/manage-dns-in-a-windows-environment-by-using-powershell.aspx).  It includes an annotated script example that can be used for exactly what you describe.

Answer (score -4):

If your DNS server software is not your friend, kick it out (if you can) and use an other one. I just see bind is working on Windows. I know bind is configured by files, with a text editor. So remove Windows DNS and put an other ! Or install a small Linux/BSD server with bind on a VM... If all zones are the same (except the domain name), you will be able to have the same file for all zones...

Comment: i am not a 1 man army... i cant go changing the infrastructure to a companys dns server. But thanks for the reply.

Comment: This is unnecessary, since Windows' DNS server is very scriptable using dnscmd.exe

Comment: **Q:** `"How do I do _____ with $product?"` - **A:** `"Use $product2 instead, of course!"`